# Compare values from 2 tables based on Dates from one of the 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables that have similar data and I need to compare the values of one table with the other where the dates are equal.

Example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [data].[ProfileReconciliation] (
[ProfileName] varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[OriginalFeedDate] datetime NOT NULL ,
[AggregationDate] datetime NOT NULL ,
[TotalDescription] varchar(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[TotalSalesAmount] decimal(18,2) NOT NULL ,
[LoadKey] int NULL 
)
ON [DATA]
GO

CREATE TABLE [data].[Aggregation] (
[ColumnName] varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[dataDate] date,
[profileDate] datetime  ,
[aggregationType] varchar(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
[dataValue] decimal(18,2) NOT NULL ,

)
ON [DATA]
GO
```

So, the `dataValue` in the `Aggregation` table needs to be compared to the `TotalSalesAmount` in the `ProfileReconciliation` table. The `dataDate` in the `Aggregation` table matches up with the `AggregationDate` in the `ProfileReconciliation` table.  The ProfileReconciliation table only contains data from a daily feed, so we only need to compare the dates that are in the ProfileReconciliation with the Aggregation table. I need to indicate weather the values of each table are equal and if not I need to show a flag indicating so. I started by selecting the data from the Aggregation table where the dataDate was in AggregationDate. I obviously have to cast the AggregationDate. I just have no clue where to head next or what the best approach to this is.

Example Data:
 From ProfileReconciliation table

```
OPDCost 2012-10-08 17:43:51.000 2012-10-07 00:00:00.000 SUM(Total_Net_Cost_Amt) 21323923.00 5307

OPDS    2012-10-08 17:43:51.000 2012-10-07 00:00:00.000 SUM(Total_Net_Sales_Amt)    70753228.00 5307
```

From Aggregation table:

```
SPVData.fact.DayStoreProdCost   2012-10-07  2012-10-09 09:06:20.9167944     20970788.131400 
SPVData.fact.DayStoreProdExtra   2012-10-07     2012-10-09 09:03:19.1558724     70642458.910000
```

So as you can see the amounts do not match up so we wwould want teh results to look like this:

```
**ProfileName  Date                      ProfileAmount AggregationAmount   Equal**
OPDCost      2012-10-07 00:00:00.000   21323923.00   20970788.13         0
OPDS         2012-10-07 00:00:00.000   70753228.00   70642458.91         0
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Word problems remind people of school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select p.ProfileName, p.AggregationDate,
p.TotalSalesAmount as ProfileAmount, a.DataValue as AggregationAmount,
Case When p.SalesAmount <> a.DataValue Then 1
else 0
end as Equal
From Aggregation a 
Inner Join ProfileReconcilation p On Convert(Date,p.AggregationDate) = a.DataDate
```

If I've understood correctly, which I'm not sure I have...

Not sure the Convert is necessary either, from your example looks like your DateTime has a data in it anyway.